# One class with a vector data member

Tags: c++, new-operator

I would like to define a class with a vector data member. The class looks as follows

```
class A{
...
private:
     std::vector<int> v1;
...
};
```

If I use operator new to allocate memory for class A, the program is OK. However, if I get the memory from the pre-allocated memory and cast the pointer to type A*, the program will crash.

```
A* a = new A;
A* b = (A*)pre_allocated_memory_pointer.
```

I need one vector with variable size and hope to get the memory for A from one pre-allocated memory. Do you have any idea about the problem?

Comment: `std::vector<>` *is* variable size, and you're "problem" is anything-but clearly represented. What is "preallocated" memory? Some raw blast of memory on which you want to *construct* an `A` (using something like placement-`new`)? Even if you do that, the `std::vector<>` member will still be using the default allocator for its memory management unless you provide a custom one of those as well (and I've a feeling thats a little further down the road than you want to travel).

Comment: You need to ensure the object's constructor is called. `new` does this, your pre-allocated memory technique probably doesn't. But why do you need the dynamic allocation anyway?

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. Because I need one variable size vector.

Comment: A vector is variable size anyway. Read some references before over-complicating your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig Pre-allocated memory is "Some raw blast of memory on which you want to construct an A".

Comment: Because I need to allocate the memory for A for many times, I use pre-allocated memory to avoid fragmentation. I use STL vector to represent variable array. I think STL can avoid memory fragmentation even if the array is variable size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `std::vector` is an object that requires initialization, you cannot just allocate memory and pretend you've got a `vector`.

If you need to control where to get the memory from the solution is defining `operator::new` for your class.

```
struct MyClass {
    std::vector<int> x;
    ... other stuff ...

    void *operator new(size_t sz) {
        ... get somewhere sz bytes and return a pointer to them ...
    }

    void operator delete(void *p) {
        ... the memory is now free ...
    }
};
```

Another option is instead to specify where to allocate the object using placement new:

```
struct MyClass {
    std::vector<int> x;
    ... other stuff ...
};

void foo() {
    void * p = ... get enough memory for sizeof(MyClass) ...

    MyClass *mcp = new (p) MyClass();

    ... later ...

    mcp->~MyClass(); // Call destructor

    ... the memory now can be reused ...
}
```

Note however that `std::vector` manages itself the memory for the contained elements and therefore you'll need to use stl "allocators" if you want to control where the memory it needs is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

It is not enough to cast the pre-allocated memory poiner to your user-defined type unless this UDT is "trivial".

Instead, you may want to use the [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html) expression to actually call the constructor of your type at the provided region of memory:

```
A* b = new(pre_allocated_memory_pointer) A();
```

Of course, you need to ensure that your memory is properly aligned and can fit the whole object (i.e. its size is >= sizeof(A) ) beforehand.

Don't also forget to explicitly call the destructor for this object before de-allocating the underlying memory.

```
b.~A();
deallocate(pre_allocated_memory_pointer);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think placement new is a good idea. However, I don't understand that "its size is >= sizeof(A)". I can only guarantee that the size of pre_allocated_memory_pointer) is equal to sizeof(A).

Comment: @JoggingSong that should be sufficient. 
The idea is that the memory region you allocate for calling a placement new with it should be no lesser than the object which is going to be constructed there. It can be greater, but having it of the exactly needed size is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question you are confusing the data memory of the `std::vector` with the memory it takes up as a member.

If you convert `pre_allocated_memory_pointer` to `A*`, then no constructor got called and you have an invalid object there. This means that the `v1` member will not have been constructed and hence no memory has been allocated for the vector.

You could use placement new to construct the `A` instance at the `pre_allocated_memory_pointer` position but I doubt that is what you want.

In my opinion you want a custom allocator for the vector that gets the memory for the vector's data from the preallocated memory pool.